# How to download all the vidoes in a youtube playlist in linux?

Tags: video-streaming, youtube-dl

Can I use youtube-dl for that? 
I've downloaded youtube videos with the help of youtube-dl but one by one. I mean to say is there any command by which I can download all the vidoes in a particular playlist?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

Use command below to download playlist:

```
youtube-dl -i -o (location) http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=XXXXXXXXXXX
```

where

```
-o, --output TEMPLATE   Output filename template, see the "OUTPUT TEMPLATE"
-i, --ignore-errors              Continue on download errors, for example to
                                 skip unavailable videos in a playlist
```

See [Output Template](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#output-template)

[Example:](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl#output-template-examples)

```
$ youtube-dl --get-filename -o '%(title)s.%(ext)s' BaW_jenozKc
youtube-dl test video ''_ä↭.mp4    # All kinds of weird characters

$ youtube-dl --get-filename -o '%(title)s.%(ext)s' BaW_jenozKc --restrict-filenames
youtube-dl_test_video_.mp4          # A simple file name

# Download YouTube playlist videos in separate directory indexed by video order in a playlist
$ youtube-dl -o '%(playlist)s/%(playlist_index)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s' https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLwiyx1dc3P2JR9N8gQaQN_BCvlSlap7re

# Download all playlists of YouTube channel/user keeping each playlist in separate directory:
$ youtube-dl -o '%(uploader)s/%(playlist)s/%(playlist_index)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s' https://www.youtube.com/user/TheLinuxFoundation/playlists

# Download Udemy course keeping each chapter in separate directory under MyVideos directory in your home
$ youtube-dl -u user -p password -o '~/MyVideos/%(playlist)s/%(chapter_number)s - %(chapter)s/%(title)s.%(ext)s' https://www.udemy.com/java-tutorial/

# Download entire series season keeping each series and each season in separate directory under C:/MyVideos
$ youtube-dl -o "C:/MyVideos/%(series)s/%(season_number)s - %(season)s/%(episode_number)s - %(episode)s.%(ext)s" http://videomore.ru/kino_v_detalayah/5_sezon/367617

# Stream the video being downloaded to stdout
$ youtube-dl -o - BaW_jenozKc
```

By default youtube-dl tries to download the best quality, but sometimes you may want to download other format so use command :

```
youtube-dl -i -o (location) -f mp4 http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=XXXXXXXXXXX
```

**Note:**

You will find Options `-citk` or `-citw` in old answers that is not needed now . Please see [youtube-dl FAQs](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#do-i-always-have-to-pass--citw).

**References:**

- [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl)
- [phihag's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42555963/5035803)

Comment: `-c` forces continuing instead of the default (continue only when formats fit) and is thus a bad idea. `-t` is superfluous. `-k` makes little sense here. Answers like this are the reason for [problems users encounter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42551972/35070).

Comment: Thanks phihag. this is old answer and still people using this option that's why they added that to FAQs.  i added your answer link here.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would divide your answer in right and wrong. Why not write an up-to-date version? I fear people may stop reading after the first example. By the way, [I wrote that FAQ entry](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/commit/573585c2347afc635b89016944c868e2ab134197).